# Chrome OS - Kiosk mode - virtual keyboard

Tags: keyboard, virtual, mode, kiosk, google-chrome-os

We are using the Chrome OS kiosk mode which can be configured in the Google Admin.
The problem that we run in is the google virtual keyboard (configured for the german language) which pops up to fill in an email address. For a customer it´s not easy to find the @ sign. For a better user experience we need a simplified virtual keyboard where the customer can easily type in the email address.

We tried to install several virtual keyboard extensions from the chrome webstore, but this extensions won´t work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Gwo.png)

The virtual keyboard in google admin doesn´t have any settings to simplify the keyboard in the way we need it.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, suffering from exactly the same problem

Comment: The Google virtual keyboard is currently still not a solution. We will rely on our own development here.

Comment: @ET97 facing the similar problem here, what did you do in the end with "our own development"? I need a way to somehow switch keyboard layout. I have a PWA+chrome extension combination deployed, both PWA and extension are developed by me.
You also mentioned "configured for the German language"...how did you changed the layout to German? I only have US English layout and didn't find how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

try [browser keyboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/browser-keyboard-perfect/fkbfahodmkmnemdhcnejmafailmahkkp) for me working OK, but not my language support